# WPF: How to get a control's property value from an event raised by a template

Tags: wpf

I need to allow the user to vertically resize a user control. So searching led me to a few examples on how to use the Thumb class and templates.  So I set up the templates:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid>
            <t:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="ScrollNS" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 0 -4" ItemResizeCompleted="ResizeThumb_ItemResizeCompleted" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Designer Item Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then I setup the ResizeThumb class:

```
Public Class ResizeThumb
Inherits Thumb

Public Event ItemResizeCompleted(sender As Object, e As TimeSlotPanelItemResizeEventArgs)
Public Property id As Integer

Public Sub New()
    AddHandler DragDelta, AddressOf ResizeThumb_DragDelta
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeThumb_DragDelta(sender As Object, e As DragDeltaEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ItemResized(sender As Object, e As DragCompletedEventArgs) Handles Me.DragCompleted
    Dim rs As ResizeThumb = CType(sender, ResizeThumb)
    Dim gd As Grid = CType(rs.Parent, Grid)

    Dim ee As New TimeSlotPanelItemResizeEventArgs
    ee.id = id
    ee.ResizeValue = e.VerticalChange
    RaiseEvent ItemResizeCompleted(Me, ee)
End Sub
End Class
```

my UserControls are added dynamically so I add the template at runtime:

```
    Dim si As New SchedItem(id, StartTime, Duration, SO, Title, UnitOfWork, BackgroundColor, Status, LastNote, Miles, Hours)
    Dim cc As ContentControl = New ContentControl
    cc.Content = si
    cc.Template = FindResource("DesignerItemTemplate")
```

Each SchedItem has an id.  Since the ResizeThumb class has a DragComplete event, I'm raising an event to pass back the VerticalChange and I want to also pass the id of the SchedItem that was resized.  I tried binding it to TemplatedParent but it's not allowed.  The only parent the ResizeThumb has is the Grid. I tried binding the Tag of the grid to the TemplatedParent but got nothing in the tag.

So now I have to ask; Is there any way to access the id property of the SchedItem from the ItemResized event handler in the ResizeThumb class?  If so, how?  If not, alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow! I figured it out.  Took me most of the day but it finally works.  Just had to figure out the correct binding to use.  So in my code, I set the Tag of the ContentControl to the id.

```
    Dim cc As ContentControl = New ContentControl
    cc.Tag = id  '<-- right here
    cc.Content = si
    cc.Template = FindResource("DesignerItemTemplate")
```

Then in the XAML, figured out how to bind that tag to the Grid that contains the ResizeThumb class's Tag property.

```
    <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Tag}">
            <t:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="ScrollNS" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 0 -4" ItemResizeCompleted="ResizeThumb_ItemResizeCompleted" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And now in the ItemResized event, I can get to the grid, which is the parent of the sender, and assign the Tag to the id of the event.

```
Private Sub ItemResized(sender As Object, e As DragCompletedEventArgs) Handles Me.DragCompleted
    Dim rs As ResizeThumb = CType(sender, ResizeThumb)
    Dim gd As Grid = CType(rs.Parent, Grid)

    Dim ee As New TimeSlotPanelItemResizeEventArgs
    ee.id = gd.Tag
    ee.ResizeValue = e.VerticalChange
    RaiseEvent ItemResizeCompleted(Me, ee)
End Sub
```

And now I get the id back in the event.